# LocationManager inconsistent

Tags: ios, objective-c, gps, core-location

I am using core location to store lat/long coordinates. I have the following code in viewDidLoad.

```
    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    self.locationManager.delegate = self;
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    self.locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters;
    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

Here is my delegate method.

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations {
    [self.locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
    CLLocation* loc = [locations lastObject]; // locations is guaranteed to have at least one object
    float latitude = loc.coordinate.latitude;
    float longitude = loc.coordinate.longitude;
    self.lat = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f",latitude];
    self.longString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f",longitude];
}
```

I'm using GPS to track these coordinates and it seems inconsistent. Upon launching the app, the location services icon does not show up often. However, if I toggle my wifi, it'll work. Or, if I open the Maps app and prompt it to obtain my current location, and then switch to my app, it'll work. Sometimes, it'll just work irregardless. If the location services icon doesn't show up then my lat/long values are null. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are immediately stopping updating locations when the very first update arrives. That's like flicking a light switch on and off so fast that there's no time for the light bulb to start glowing. It takes time and several updates for all the sensors to warm up and get a decent fix, especially the GPS. You need to allow enough updates to arrive until you do in fact have a location (and you probably want to check the accuracy to make sure it is a reasonably accurate location).

Comment: Here's code that shows you how to keep trying just long enough to get a good location value or else to time out after a reasonable amount of time: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch22p773location/ch35p1032location/ViewController.m

Comment: Hmmm...I still have the same issues even after implementing that code. Also, the "this is taking too long" NSlog doesn't show up, so I'm not sure if it's even reaching the delegate. It's almost as if I need to turn the GPS on via imaps to get it to work.

Comment: My example is downloadable and is a complete working project. Try it as it stands.

Comment: I've already copied and pasted it into code that I already have and it's still inconsistent.

Comment: The first location that you get back is usually the *cached* location that was saved, it can be minutes or hours old.  You need to check the timestamp and accuracy of locations until you find a good one.

Comment: If you "copy and paste" I don't know what you're doing; you might not be setting up the instance variables correctly, for example. Please do what I'm suggesting: test the _actual_ example project I'm providing you. You'll find that it works.